# How to make modal not popup when loading the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

this is my first website and i kinda just copy pasted the js script for the popup. everything is ok but everytime the page is refreshed a popup shows even though its set so its only when i click an image.

heres the code that i used for the overlay

```
<div class="overlay" id="overlay">
            <div class="popup-container">
                <span class="close-btn" onclick="closePopup()">&times;</span>
                <img src="" alt="Popup Image" class="popup-image" id="popup-image">
                <div class="text-box" id="popup-text">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and heres the js script

```
<script>
        function openPopup(name, sex, birthday, age, color, description) {
    var overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');

    if (overlay) {
        overlay.style.display = 'flex';
        document.getElementById('popup-image').src = `images/${name.toLowerCase()}.jpg`;
        document.getElementById('popup-text').innerHTML = `
            <p>Name: ${name}</p>
            <p>Sex: ${sex}</p>
            <p>Birthday: ${birthday}</p>
            <p>Age: ${age}</p>
            <p>Color: ${color}</p>
            <p>Description: ${description}</p>`;
    }
}

    
        function closePopup() {
            document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: You'd need to set the popup to be hidden by default. Usually this means adding CSS for that. If you already do that, edit your answer to show that.

Comment: sorry if this is a stupid question but how do I do this exactly, i already set the .overlay class that i use to display: none: but its not working

Comment: You'll need to add that to your question. If you do indeed have `.overlay { display: none; }` in your css, then the issue is with something not shown in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Change the first line of your HTML from

```
<div class="overlay" id="overlay">
```

to

```
<div class="overlay" id="overlay" style="display:none">
```